# The InfiniteList widget calls onFetchData when it is just initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

The InfiniteList widget calls onFetchData when it is just initialized
in pub dev Very Good Infinite List

```
InfiniteList(
   isLoading: state.loadMore,
   loadingBuilder: (context) => widgetLoadMore(),
   onFetchData: () { // calls onFetchData when it is just initialized }
```

I'm catching the event to check for the first time and it looks really annoying

```
bool canLoadMore = false;

onFetchData: () {
        if (canLoadMore) {
          bloc.add(GetMore());
        } else {
             canLoadMore = true;
        }
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is actually how the widget works. The widget tries to call the `onFetchData` in the `initState` method, as you can see in the code below (this is the SliverInfiniteList `initState`). The conditions for this to happen are: it should NOT reach the max list size, it should NOT be loading, and it should NOT have an error.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    debounce = CallbackDebouncer(widget.debounceDuration);
    attemptFetch();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(SliverInfiniteList oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (!widget.hasReachedMax && oldWidget.hasReachedMax) {
      attemptFetch();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    debounce.dispose();
  }

  void attemptFetch() {
    if (!widget.hasReachedMax && !widget.isLoading && !widget.hasError) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        debounce(widget.onFetchData);
      });
    }
  }
```

I think the best workaround for you is to create a widget with this list that validates whether it should call onFetchData on the first load. For example:

Create a widget like this as an abstraction to the infinite list

```
class PaginatedList extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaginatedList({
    super.key,
    required this.itemCount,
    required this.onFetchData,
    required this.itemBuilder,
    required this.isLoading,
    this.shouldFetchOnFirstLoad = false
  });

  final bool shouldFetchOnFirstLoad;
  final VoidCallback onFetchData;
  final int itemCount;
  final bool isLoading;
  final ItemBuilder itemBuilder;

  @override
  State<PaginatedList> createState() => _PaginatedListState();
}

class _PaginatedListState extends State<PaginatedList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InfiniteList(
      itemCount: widget.itemCount,
      isLoading: widget.isLoading,
      onFetchData: () {
        if(widget.shouldFetchOnFirstLoad) {
          widget.onFetchData.call();
        }
      },
      itemBuilder: widget.itemBuilder,
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Simple Example'),
      ),
      body: PaginatedList(
        itemCount: _items.length,
        isLoading: _isLoading,
        onFetchData: _fetchData,
        shouldFetchOnFirstLoad: false,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            dense: true,
            title: Text(_items[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: If you set the variable ``this.shouldFetchOnFirstLoad = false`` as you instructed, the loadmore action will no longer be performed, because the variable ``shouldFetchOnFirstLoad`` will prevent the function from being performed.

, I am using package https://pub.dev/documentation/very_good_infinite_list/latest/

Comment: Yes, before the initial load, you can change the variable on your bloc, and the validation to fetch or not is the responsibility of the widget, not the entire screen. As I mentioned, it is the best workaround in my opinion, but there are others that you can try (Considering the way that the widget operates).